# Read a csv into a multidimensional array in Matlab

Tags: matlab, file-io, csv

I have a 13x13x100 array, L,  of doubles that I write out using `csvwrite(L, 'file.csv');`. This produces a csv with 13 rows and 1300 columns, so using `M=csvread('file.csv');` gives a 13x1300 array. Is there a smarter way to write this out or read this in so that M = L? Alternatively, is there an easy way to convert M from 13x1300 to 13x13x100?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `reshape()` function to convert M as you describe

```
M = reshape(M, [13 13 100]);
```

The matrix elements are assigned column-wise, which is almost certainly what you want. Check the help for `reshape()`